# How to apply Array.Sort to Collection<T>?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list, collections

I have a collection(the collection is sort of big > 100K custom complex items in it and adding new items happens really often).
I need to sort it just once - before showing it.
To simplify my question lets say that I have a collection of integers that I need to sort:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var collection = new Collection<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
    var array = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

    // How to apply Array.Sort to Collection<T> ?
    list.Sort();       //ok
    Array.Sort(array); //ok
}
```

Basically `list.Sort();` uses `Array.Sort<T>(this._items, index, count, comparer);`

How can I sort my `Collection<T>` ?
(without copying)

Comment: I can't understand the reason you can't use list.sort()

Comment: @AntonioGanci because a `Collection<T>` isn't a `List<T>`, and `Collection<T>` doesn't have `Sort()` ?

Comment: @AntonioGanci the reason is Microsoft rule CA 1002(
Warning CA1002 Change 'List<T>' in 'IMyInterface.MyList' to use Collection<T>, ReadOnlyCollection<T> or KeyedCollection<K,V>)

Comment: @isxaker I'd suppress that rule, quite honestly... things like that *only* apply if you're a library author who is shipping libraries to be consumed by other folks, and *even then* it is questionable; if you're an *app* developer (i.e. your code is just used by your own systems, or systems that your colleagues can easily tweak): forget about it

Comment: @mjwills I use `List<T>` right now. However microsft rules(code analysis) suggests to me to use to use `Collection<T>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` or `KeyedCollection<K,V>`(`Warning CA1002`) And I'm trying to do it. Before suppress it I would like to make a research is it possible or not, is it worth is or not.

Comment: Ignore the 'rule'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no convenient way to do this; `Collection<T>` doesn't provide raw access to the internal buffer, even for sub-classes (`protected`). Without that, you can't do a clean in-place sort.

You could manually implement a sort on the underlying `.Items` (`protected`), but it is a lot of work and will be inefficient.

What you *could* also do is:

- lease an array from the array pool
- copy the data from the local collection to the leased array
- sort that array
- either clear and re-add everything from the now-sorted array, or overwrite the items index-by-index from the now-sorted-array
- return the leased array to the array pool

However, personally I'd probably say "if you need to sort, use `List<T>`" - it'll save you a lot of work.

Comment: *lease an array from the array pool*—never heard C# arrays talked about in this way. I get the gist of it, but is this official terminology or a convenient metaphor or...?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble example: `int[] leasedArray = ArrayPool<int>.Shared.Rent(minimumSize); /* TODO: use it ... */ ArrayPool<int>.Shared.Return(leasedArray);` etc - note that leased arrays are **over-sized** (i.e. if you ask for an array of at least 100, it might lend you one sized 128) - this is from System.Buffers

Comment: I see... any reason to do this and *not* `new T[size]` since the size is known?

Comment: @d.benknoble The reasoning would be performance because the one in pool may already have a block of memory allocated to it and you're just renting it. Think renting an apartment vs building one from scratch ;)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble allocations; fewer are typically better